# Actions on Google Simulator

Tags: actions-on-google

I worked on one Google assistant, I used Dialog Flow and I constantly tested in the simulator.
But today I woke up, started the project, and the simulator does not show me Google actions (list or basic card), although I did not change anything in the project. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwMmc.png)

Comment: Can you include a screen shot that shows the entire simulator that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I added a link in the question.